# GAE - replacement for vm:true flag on app.yaml

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible

I've been using the standard environment setting `vm:true` on my app.yaml

I know that this flag is now deprecated and I won't be able to use it in the future... I also know that Flexible Environment is currently in Beta, so my question is, will `env:flex` be the replacement for `vm:true`? If so will it be stable by then?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general Beta products come with no SLA and this is highlighted on [App Engine Flexible Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/):

> This is a Beta release of the App Engine flexible environment. It is
>   not covered by any SLA or deprecation policy and the implementation
>   may change, possibly in backward-incompatible ways. It is not
>   recommended for production use.

However, there is this note in [Upgrading to the Latest App Engine Flexible Environment Beta Release](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/upgrading#applications_created_with_vmtrue) (emphasis mine):

> All applications created in the `vm:true` environment will continue to
>   work **for at least 6 months after** the App Engine flexible
>   environment becomes generally available. At that point, all customers
>   need to switch to the `env:flex` environment.