# HTTP header case

Tags: node.js

I am dealing with server, which is not accepting uncapitalized headers and unfortunately I can't do much with it.

```
var headers = {};
headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36';
headers['Accept'] = 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8';
headers['Connection'] = 'keep-alive';
headers['Cache-Control'] = 'max-age=0';
headers['Upgrade-Insecure-Requests'] = '1';
headers['Accept-Encoding'] = 'gzip, deflate';
headers['Accept-Language'] = 'en-US,en;q=0.9,ru;q=0.8,hy;q=0.7';

request.post({url: 'http://10.10.10.10/login', headers: headers, ...
```

this in fact sending out the following

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,ru;q=0.8,hy;q=0.7
DNT: 1
host: 10.10.10.10
cookie: vvv=765936875155218941
```

`cookie` and `host` are lower cased. How can I alter `request`, to send out capitalized headers?

Comment: Header names are case-insensitive, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258977/are-http-headers-case-sensitive .

Comment: I know it, but for some reason the server is not respecting this and I need to find workaround.

Comment: Are you saying that `http://10.10.10.10/login` doesn't behave correctly with lower-cased `host` and `cookie`? Are you sure that this is the real problem with request and not anything else? Seems like it's server's problem in the first place, it's not spec-compilant.

Comment: I'm sure because I tried to simulate it through Fiddle. Changing the `cookie` to `Cookie` is successfully authenticating user.

Comment: Consider reporting this as a bug then if it's your or friendly server. Any way, I provided a workaround, I would expect it to work.

Comment: It's an enemy server :) I'm trying now the workaround you proposed. Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not Node.js issue but a supposed issue with particular library, `request`. In fact, not an issue at all because [HTTP headers are case-insensitive](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2). `request` uses `caseless` package to enforce lower-cased headers, so it's expected that user headers will be lower-case if consistency is required.

These headers may be left as is, as they should be handled correctly by remote server according to the specs.

It may be necessary to specific header case if a request is supposed to mimic real client request. In this case header object can be traversed manually before a request, e.g.:

```
const normalizeHeaderCase = require("header-case-normalizer");

const req = request.post('...', { headers: ... });

for (const [name, value] of Object.entries(req.headers)) {
    delete req.headers[name];
    req.headers[normalizeHeaderCase(name)] =  value;
}

req.on('response', function(response) {...});
```

Comment: basically I can no more use `function (error, response, body) {...}` callback and need to buffer data using `.on('data', ...)` ?

Comment: I expect that request callback can be used as well.

Comment: With request callback it works as well, but as far as I understand, once `request.post(...)` line passed, connection is starting. Not sure if a separate thread is spawn for it, but what can guarantee, that at the time of header normalization, the request not already sent out? Could race condition happen here?

Comment: Seems like it's ok. The actual request starts when request(...).start() is called internally, and it's called on next tick.